# Android make EditText Visible and invisible again

Tags: android, visibility

I am Making an Android app for rowers and paddlers. With different boat sizes. Like a Kajak with only One Pladler and a Dragonboat with 20 Paddlers.
I am Trying to create all of them and show only the ones i need for the typ boat chosen.
My Problem is i can't make a spinner invissible and Visible again.
My code is some what like this:

```
public class DayTripActivity extends Activity {
    private boolean visible = true;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // setContentView(R.layout.day_trip);
        ScrollView scrollView = new ScrollView(this);

        final LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL); 
        scrollView.addView(linearLayout);
        this.setContentView(scrollView);

        for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
            TextView tvCrew = new TextView(this);
            tvCrew.setText("Crewmember "+i);
            tvCrew.setId(ID_Crew_TEXTVIEW+i);
            linearLayout.addView(tvCrew);
        }

        Button btndatePicker = new Button(this);
        btndatePicker.setText("Make Drummer 2 invisible / visible");
        btndatePicker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                if(visible){
                        linearLayout.findViewById(ID_DRUMMER_TEXTVIEW+1).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }else{
                    linearLayout.findViewById(ID_DRUMMER_TEXTVIEW+1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                visible = !visible;
            }
        });
        linearLayout.addView(btndatePicker);
```

Comment: I see that you create a variable 'visible' and set it to true. If you notice, it is declared in the onCreate method scope. However, you're creating an anonymous handler for the spinner so 'visible' is not in the same scope. Move 'boolean visible' outside of the method (e.g. make it a class variable).

Comment: In my original Code the Variable is out side of the code. let me correct the Errors.